# sum of legendre symbol of quadratic non-residue power

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

[image: question]

What I have done is that

> $$\left(\dfrac 1 p\right)+\left(\dfrac a p\right)+\left(\dfrac {a^2} p\right)+\ldots +\left(\dfrac {a^{d-1}} p\right)$$

in this, $\left(\dfrac 1 p\right)=1$, $\left(\dfrac a p\right)=-1$ by assumption. but from $2$ to $d-1$, what can I do?

I think that it will use property of the number of quadratic residue which is $\dfrac {p-1} 2$ and non residue is equal but, in this case, we consider 1~d-1 so I don't know how to apply

Comment: Use $$\left(\dfrac{ab}p\right)=\left(\dfrac ap\right)\left(\dfrac bp\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $\left({\cdot\over\cdot}\right)$ is a homomorphism from $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z^\times$ to the group $\{\pm 1\}$. But then the kernel has size ${p-1\over 2}$ by Lagrange's theorem. Then the other half of the elements map to $-1$. So you have exactly ${p-1\over 2}$ $+1$s and the same number of $-1$s, so they all cancel out in the sum. In your case, you are looking at a non-square generated subgroup, so you get the same division, in particular you know the kernel intersects $\langle a\rangle$ in an index $2$ subgroup, so the same thing applies to subgroups generated by non-squares.

Comment: It is not summing over all residues and non-residues, IMHO. I think it is necessary to show that $d$ is even, which is true since $a$ is a non-residue.

Comment: Then, the order of quadratic non residue is always even (mod p) and also, the order of quadratic residue is always odd?

Comment: i think that the order of quadratic non residue is always even (mod p) and  the order of quadratic residue is not always odd but the order divided pi(n)/2

Comment: @awllower why not? Everything is either a residue or a non-residue. So summing all the things is the same as summing all residues and all non-residues. Since $a$ is a non-residue, every other one is going to be a residue, and the rest are non-residues.

Comment: Yes, you need the fact that the kernel intersects $\left<a\right>$ in an index-$2$ subgroup. But if $d$ is odd then this is impossible. I mean: the things that are summed are not *exactly* all residues and non-residues, so maybe some more explanations are in need: notice that we only sum $d$ symbols.

Comment: @awllower yes, but you don't need to prove this explicitly. It is sufficient to show the intersection is an index $2$ subgroup without explicitly showing that $d\equiv 0\mod 2$. You could, but it would be redundant.

Comment: Ok, I did not notice this previously; thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Do you know that $\left(\dfrac{ab}{p}\right)=\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)\left(\dfrac{b}{p}\right)$ for $a,b$ prime to $p?$ Also, can you show that $d$ is even?

Comment: oh oh thanks. but how can i show that d is even?

Comment: is that right? suppose that d is odd then, $a^d=1 (modp) $ by using arithmetic inverse, $a=(a'^k)^2 (modp)$ a' is inverse. so contradiction

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct. :)